# tapestry layouts and component libraries

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a few different projects that basically use the same javascript/css and layout template. I want to move all of this into my tapestry-common-lib project and reference it from there.

I have other common components in my tapestry-common-lib, but can't seem to get the layout to work properly.

In my tapestry-common-lib project I have a CommonLayout.java in `com.company.tapestrylib.components` 
and a CommonLayout.tml file under 
`com/company/tapestrylib/components`.

I am trying to reference the CommonLayout form another project in my Index.tml like so:

```
<t:commonlayout  xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd">
</t:commonlayout>
```

However, whenever I access that page I get a

```
Unable to resolve 'commonlayout' to a component class name.
```

Can I do this? Can I also put all of my common css and javascript into my tapestry-common-lib jar and reference those from there using for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${asset:context:/js/jquery-1.4.2.js}"></script>
```

I've been looking around and have found plenty of articles on creating custom components and component libraries, but none that reused layouts like I am trying to do.

UPDATE:

I am currently using other abstract components from my component library. These are stored in [root].tapestrylib.base.

I am trying to store my common layout (Layout.java and Layout.tml) in [root].tapestrylib.components. When trying to refer to this layout from my other project, I get a

```
Unable to resolve 'layout' to a component class name.
```

I am trying to use it like so:

```
<html t:type="tapestry-lib/layout" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
</html>
```

This is part of the actual exception I am getting:

```
11:28:01 ERROR RequestExceptionHandler - Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: Unable to resolve 'tapestry-lib/layout' to a component class name.
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: Unable to resolve 'tapestry-lib/layout' to a component class name. [at classpath:com/mycompany/webapp/pages/Index.tml, line 1]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1057)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.createAssembler(PageLoaderImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.getAssembler(PageLoaderImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1057)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.loadPage(PageLoaderImpl.java:173)
    at $PageLoader_12d045be613.loadPage($PageLoader_12d045be613.java)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layout or non-layout component should not make a difference.

Are any of the components from your library available? (The full error report [`tapestry.production-mode=false`] gives you a list of available components.) If not, your library probably isn't set up properly.

Tapestry finds component libraries by scanning the manifest files of all JARs on the classpath for an entry called `Tapestry-Module-Classes`, and loads the component module configuration from there. Check if the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in your JAR has such an entry, and if it references the correct component module class.

The [component library section in the Tapestry docs](https://tapestry.apache.org/component-libraries.html) shows how to set up Maven to automatically create such an entry.

*Edit:*

The components need to be in the package that you configured for them in your module class:

```
public class MyTapestryComponentsModule {

   public static void contributeComponentClassResolver(
            Configuration<LibraryMapping> configuration) {
        configuration.add(
            new LibraryMapping("myprefix", "my.tapestry.basepackage"));
   }

}
```

So any components would go into `my.tapestry.basepackage.components`, mixins into `my.tapestry.basepackage.mixins`, etc., just like in your main app.

To use the components from your library, you just prefix them with whatever you defined:

```
<div t:type="myprefix/MyComponent" ... />
```

*Edit 2:*

Okay, that looks fine. What would be really useful to see is the list of available components Tapestry logs at startup. It is located right above the list of services that are printed last after startup, and should look like this:

```
2010-12-20 20:27:07,663 [main] INFO  org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.ComponentClassResolver - Available components:
  ActionLink: org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.ActionLink
  AddRowLink: org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.AddRowLink
  etc.
```

Your components should show up there with their full name and prefix. Do they?

Comment: Also check out what available components do you have at your web app start up. The log should contain a list of all available ones - core and from any component libs you have properly set up.

Comment: I checked all of this and I have it configured properly as I am using a few common abstract base components from my component library. Perhaps I am placing the common layout in the wrong place? I have it in my tapestrylib.components package.

Comment: @Casey: A working base class merely means that the JAR is on the classpath, not that your component lib is configured. What have you checked? Are the components available in your application? (See the error report page or the log output at startup for a complete list of loaded components.) If not: Do you have a component module class, and does it configure the right base package for your module? (See edit.) If yes: Does your manifest file contain a reference to that component class? If yes: Does the log output on startup say anything about a failed component lib?

Comment: The JAR contains the correct class path entry. My Library mapping is "tapestry-lib". In the log it says that it added the module definition. No exceptions that I can find regarding that. I do have a component module class and it is configured with the correct base class.

Comment: Good. Then what does the log output/error report say? Are the components present?

Comment: I added the exception from the log that I get when I try to access a page containing that uses the layout.

Comment: As far as I can tell, tapestry is finding the components. I don't see anything specific about the Layout that I am using however.

Comment: @Casey: Okay, that looks fine. We need to find out if Tapestry has found your components, see edit 2.

Comment: So it appears that after doing a complete clean of both projects and rebuilding that I was not properly referring to the correct packages. In my real project in the common module I missed an upper level folder name in the package section.